# pythonic way to check if any elements of a list is present in a set

Tags: python, list, set, list-comprehension

Trying to find a way to check the following:

```
approved_countries = ['Germany', 'France']
```

We have 5 sets :

```
{'Germany'}
{'Germany', 'France'}
{'Germany', 'France'}
{'Germany'}
{'Germany', 'Italy'}
```

**I need to iterate through the *sets* and flag the sets that have a country which is not present in the *list* of approved countries.**

So in this case I would need to flag the set that contains Italy.

What would be the most pythonic way of achieving this?

Comment: Please specify if you want a solution for a dtaframe or your set,  because that can change the way to solve the issue. If it is a dataframe, please provide a sample dataframe

Comment: @Andreas makes sense. I've clarified the post. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for index,row in enumerate(dataset):
    if any([i not in approved_countries for i in row)):
        print("Row {} is bad".format(index))
```